# How do i get just the contents out of a select column in a Winforms Listview control in C#?

Tags: c#, listview, loops, foreach

I've added the contents of a folder to a Listview control and it looks like the image below.

[image]

When I trying to work with each item select from this Foreach loop...

```
   foreach (ListViewItem file in listView1.CheckedItems)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(file.ToString());
   }
```

I get more than what I want. I just want the file and its path.

[image]

Is my loop incorrect? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use the [`ListViewItem.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.text.aspx) property in place of `ToString()` method.

So the code stands :

```
foreach (ListViewItem file in listView1.CheckedItems)
{
    MessageBox.Show(file.Text);
}
```

Comment: Boy I could have sworn I tried that. But you're right. That did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken this should work for you:

```
file.SubItems[1].Text;
```

Comment: It gives me the exact same message.

Comment: I think the first column starts at index 1 actually, `file.SubItems[1].Text` (Updated my answer)